# Electron BrowserWindow is black after doing .show()

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

**Edit:**

It seems like the problem had something to do with the order in which I made the windows. I did the following before:

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow();
    spawnLoadingBlockWindow();
    spawnGeneratingBlockWindow();
    

    // iOS specific check. Honestly makes no sense that
    // I have this here as this program doesn't support
    // iOS anyway.
    app.on('activate', () => {
        if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) createWindow();
    })
});
```

but after switching the order of the spawning of the two popup windows, the problem has gone away. I still have no idea why this makes a difference - does anyone know?

**Original text:**

I'm making an Electron app and am currently making a popup window that says "Loading...". This window is set to not be shown by default, and then I call a function that moves and shows it when I want to.

My problem is that, seemingly at random, this popup is fully black:

[Image of the black popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeJcD.png)

This does not happen all of the time, but stays consistent for the entire life of the application; so if I close and start it again, sometimes it works properly (but it mostly doesn't).

The popup is made like this:

```js
async function spawnLoadingBlockWindow() {
    loadingWin = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 250,
        height: 75,
        center: true,
        frame: false,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js'),
        },
        parent: mainWindow,
        modal: true,
        show: false
    });

    loadingWin.loadFile('loadingPopup.html');
}
```

And I use the following function to show it:

```js
function showPopup(popupWin) {
    const winPosition = mainWindow.getPosition();
    const winSize = mainWindow.getSize();
    popupWin.setPosition(winPosition[0] + Math.round(winSize[0] / 2) - Math.round(popupWin.getSize()[0] / 2), winPosition[1] + Math.round(winSize[1] / 2) - Math.round(popupWin.getSize()[1] / 2));

    popupWin.show();
}
```

I have tried reloading the BrowserWindow using `.reload()`, which makes no difference. I have also tested it with `show` being set to true, in which case the window is not black (but I can't really use it like that because it has to be hidden up until the point I call the above function). If it helps in any way, this is the exact context in which I call the `showPopup` function:

```js
async function saveBlockInTemp(event, block) {
    clearTemp();
    showPopup(loadingWin);
    await sleep(100);
    decompressTexturesAndMoveToTemp(block);
    decompressRecipePreviewAndMoveToTemp(block);
    loadingWin.hide();
    temp = block;
    return true;
}
```

Here I use a sleep function that just waits 100ms because the next two decompressing functions call `execSync` a lot of times, resulting in the program waiting. Without the 100ms of sleep the popup window never loads properly at all and simply shows an outline with a transparent background. I have another popup that does this as well but with no problems regarding being fully black.

Answer (score 0):

as a workaround, try to launch the electron app with Hardware Acceleration turned OFF, this did work for me to get rid of the black popup window on certain machines issue.

Add this at the very beginning of the main process code:

```
app.disableHardwareAcceleration()
```